# How to setup the E-Mail client (add new account)

Tags: microsoft-outlook

What is a mail server where can i got those? 
How that works and how to identify if its a mail server before I proceed the action I encounter this (imap@gmail.com) what was it? 
Is it the mail server but when I finally added that something it went error.

[image]

Comment: Choose automatic it will do all necessary settings.

Comment: @vembutech not if he didnt set up his gmail account yet to allow IMAP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960
Please follow this guide. it contains everything you need to do to make Outlook work with gmail (and the other way around)

**Step 1: Enable IMAP**

You can retrieve your Gmail messages with a client or device that supports IMAP, like Microsoft Outlook or Apple Mail.

1. Sign in to Gmail.
2. Click the gear in the top right .
3. Select Settings.
4. Click Forwarding and POP/IMAP.
5. Select Enable IMAP.
6. Click Save Changes.

Note: This setting is not available while using the basic HTML view of Gmail. To enable IMAP, use the standard view instead. Find out more about standard view and basic HTML view. https://support.google.com/mail/answer/15049

**Step 2: Set up your client**
**Incoming mail settings:**

- Email server: imap.gmail.com
- Requires SSL: Yes
- Port: 993

**Outgoing mail settings**

- smtp server: smtp.gmail.com
- Use Authentication: Yes
- Port for SSL: 465 or 587
- Use same settings as incoming mail server

**Account Name, Emailaddress or User Name:**
Your full emailaddress

**Password:**
Your gmail password

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: @DavidPostill  done, Thanks for the suggestion